# How to ignore initial non-numeric chars in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, case

I have two tables TXN_COUNT(ACCT_NUM, SRC) and tb_acct(acct_num, source)

TXN_COUNT. ACCT_NUM has following values -

```
DDA2323  
GOLDE434  
VDA-10345  
.  
.  
.
```

Some rows have 3, some rows have 4,5 whereas some rows have 6 initial non numeric chars. Some rows don't have any non numeric chars. My goal is to ignore the non numeric  chars and join the numeric portion from TXN_COUNT.ACCT_NUM on tb_acct.acct_num (tb_acct table has correct numeric account numbers) and return the correct acct_num from tb_acct table.

Can this be possible by joining in a case statement? I am using sql server.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to attempt the join using `like`:

```
from TXN_COUNT c join
     tb_acct a
     on c.acct_num like '%[^0-9]' + cast(a.acct_num as varchar(255))
```

This will work, if you assume that there is always at least one non-numeric character prepending the number.

EDIT:

If some don't have any preceding non-numeric characters, you can do:

```
from TXN_COUNT c join
     tb_acct a
     on c.acct_num like '%[^0-9]' + cast(a.acct_num as varchar(255)) OR
        c.acct_num = cast(a.acct_num as varchar(255)
```

Comment: Some acct numbers dont have any non numeric chars. sorry, I have edited my question now.

Comment: you don't need to add **[^0-9]** in like, removing this piece will not affect the output.